# Range Slider with Thumb and Runnable Track having different opacities

Tags: css, slider

I am trying to create a slider with the runnable track and thumb having different opacities.

The following picture illustrates what i am trying to achieve.
[image]

However, if I change the opacity of the runnable track and the thumb

```
input[type=range].vslider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #444;
  height: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

input[type=range].vslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

,the thumb gets the same opacity as the runnable track.

So my question is, is it even possible to for the runnable track to have an opacity smaller than the thumbs opacity?

Comment: use rgba as color and not opacity

Comment: It really worked!
I thought rgba and opacity have the same effect. Thank you Temani Afif!

Comment: no, rgba affect only the color and opacity the whole element